# Unable to apply animation for PNotify in Angular app

Tags: angular, pnotify

I am using PNotify for alert message in angular app. I have applied animation, but animation is not working.

Below is the code that which I am using.

```
PNotify.notice({
          title: 'Animate.css Effect',
          text: 'Part Quantity is greater.',
          modules: {
            Animate: {
              animate: true,
              inClass: 'rotateInDownLeft',
              outClass: 'rotateOutUpRight'
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: Do you have `BrowserAnimationsModule` included in the module?

Comment: Yes, `BrowserAnimationsModule` is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using different modules apart from`app.module.ts`, include `BrowserAnimationsModule` in those modules also. 
hope it will solve.